# Unpack dict entries inside a function

Tags: julia

I want to unpack parameters that are stored in a dictionary. They should be available inside the local scope of a function afterwards. The name should be the same as the key which is a symbol.

```
macro unpack_dict()
    code = :()
    for (k,v) in dict
        ex = :($k = $v)
        code = quote
            $code
            $ex
        end
    end
    return esc(code)
end

function assign_parameters(dict::Dict{Symbol, T}) where T<:Any
    @unpack_dict
    return a + b - c
end

dict = Dict(:a => 1,
            :b => 5,
            :c => 6)

assign_parameters(dict)
```

However, this code throws:

```
LoadError: UndefVarError: dict not defined
```

If I define the dictionary before the macro it works because the dictionary is defined.

Does someone has an idea how to solve this? Using `eval()` works but is evaluated in the global scope what I want to avoid.

Comment: Never tested, but [Parameters.jl](https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl) seems promising. There is a [juliacon2018 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFrzrTYFYbU&index=62&list=PLP8iPy9hna6Qsq5_-zrg0NTwqDSDYtfQB) about this package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to unpack them then the best method is to simply unpack them directly:

```
function actual_fun(d)
    a = d[:a]
    b = d[:b]
    c = d[:c]
    a+b+c
end
```

This will be type stable, relatively fast and readable.

You could, for instance, do something like this (I present you two options to avoid direct assignment to `a`, `b`, and `c` variables):

```
called_fun(d) = helper(;d...)
helper(;kw...) = actual_fun(;values(kw)...)
actual_fun(;a,b,c, kw...) = a+b+c

function called_fun2(d::Dict{T,S}) where {T,S}
    actual_fun(;NamedTuple{Tuple(keys(d)), NTuple{length(d), S}}(values(d))...)
end
```

and now you can write something like:

```
julia> d = Dict(:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4)
Dict{Symbol,Int64} with 4 entries:
  :a => 1
  :b => 2
  :d => 4
  :c => 3

julia> called_fun(d)
6

julia> called_fun2(d)
6
```

But I would not recommend it - it is not type stable and not very readable.

AFACT other possibilities will have similar shortcomings as during compile time Julia knows only types of variables not their values.

EDIT: You can do something like this:

```
function unpack_dict(dict)
    ex = :()
    for (k,v) in dict
        ex = :($ex; $k = $v)
    end
    return :(myfun() = ($ex; a+b+c))
end

runner(d) = eval(unpack_dict(d))
```

and then run:

```
julia> d = Dict(:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4)
Dict{Symbol,Int64} with 4 entries:
  :a => 1
  :b => 2
  :d => 4
  :c => 3

julia> runner(d)
myfun (generic function with 1 method)

julia> myfun()
6
```

but again - I feel this is a bit messy.

Comment: Thank for your answer. In my actual problem I have plenty of parameters that are used in JuMP-Model. In order to make the model more readable I wanted to make the parameters not coming from a dictionary.

So I guess I will stick to the simple solution using
  `a = d[:a]
  b = d[:b]
  c = d[:c]` etc. and assign them manually.

Comment: From my experience, unless you have e.g. 100 such parameters (in which case probably it is better to store them in a collection anyway), this will be the most readable solution if you come back to your code in 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

In Julia 1.7, you can simply unpack named tuples into the local scope, and you can easily "spread" a dict into a named tuple.

```
julia> dict = Dict(:a => 1, :b => 5, :c => 6)
Dict{Symbol, Int64} with 3 entries:
  :a => 1
  :b => 5
  :c => 6

julia> (; a, b, c) = (; sort(dict)...)
(a = 1, b = 5, c = 6)

julia> a, b, c
(1, 5, 6)
```

(The dict keys are sorted so that the named tuple produced is type-stable; if the keys were produced in arbitrary order then this would result in a named tuple with fields in arbitrary order as well.)